# QCompleter и динамическое отсеивание записей в таблице QTableWidget

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5, autocomplete

товарищи.

Допиливаю приложение для ведения учета присвоенных децимальных номеров на предприятии.

Опишу ситуацию.

Инструменты: `PyQt5`, `python2.7`, `SQLite3`.

В главном окне присутствует `QLineEdit` с установленным `QCompleter`, также тут расположена таблица с существующими децимальными номерами. Модель `QCompleter` являет собой `QStringListModel`в которой находятся все децимальные номера из таблицы.

`QCompleter` работает замечательно, также прикрутил функцию, для автоцентрирования курсора таблицы на вводимом номере:

```
self.ui.lineEdit_decimal.textEdited.connect(self.autocenter)

def autocenter(self):
    entered_num = self.ui.lineEdit_decimal.text()
    for i in self.decimal_numbers_only:
        if entered_num == i[:len(entered_num)]:
            for i in range(len(self.decimal_numbers_only)):
                try:
                    if self.ui.table.item(i, 0).data(0)[5:5 + len(entered_num)] == entered_num:
                        self.ui.table.clearSelection()
                        self.ui.table.setRangeSelected(QTableWidgetSelectionRange(i, 1, i, 0), True)
                        self.ui.table.scrollToItem(self.ui.table.item(i, 0), QAbstractItemView.PositionAtCenter)
                        break
                except AttributeError:
                    break
```

Топорно, конечно, но, как смог. В чем загвоздка, хочется запилить отсеивание неподходящих номеров из таблицы, как поиск в `windows`. Что не подходит, в таблице не показывается. Реализовать попытался таким вот способом:

```
def autocenter(self):
    entered_num = self.ui.lineEdit_decimal.text()
    for i in self.decimal_numbers_only:
        if entered_num == i[:len(entered_num)]:
            for i in range(len(self.decimal_numbers_only)):
                try:
                    if self.ui.table.item(i, 0).data(0)[5:5 + len(entered_num)] == entered_num:
                        self.ui.table.clearSelection()
                        self.ui.table.setRangeSelected(QTableWidgetSelectionRange(i, 1, i, 0), True)
                        self.ui.table.scrollToItem(self.ui.table.item(i, 0), QAbstractItemView.PositionAtCenter)
                        break
                except AttributeError:
                    break
    self.completer_flag = 1
    self.mainTableFiller(entered_num)
```

Вызываю при вводе в `QLineEdit` функцию `self.mainTableFiller(entered_num)`, это функция, производящая заполнение `QTableWidget`. Полностью её приводить не буду, но вот основная часть:

```
def mainTableFiller(self, entered_n=''):
    # Take a list of tuples of existed decimal numbers for current phase and decimal code.
    self.existed_decimals = c.execute(
        "SELECT DISTINCT decimal FROM '%s' WHERE delflag=0 AND litera='%s' AND decimal LIKE '%s'" %
        (curent_table, curent_litera, 'f' + entered_n + '%')).fetchall()
    # Creating empty lists
    files_4_table = []
    self.decimal_numbers_only = []
    # Adding filenames into list
    for tablename in self.existed_decimals:
        if tablename[0][0] == 'f':
            files_4_table.append(tablename)
    files_4_table.sort()
    self.ui.table.setRowCount(len(files_4_table))
    self.ui.checkBox.setChecked(False)
    # Fill the table
    all_files_cur_lit = c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*), recordnumber FROM '%s' WHERE delflag=0 AND litera='%s' "
                                  "AND decimal LIKE '%s' GROUP BY decimal" %
                                  (curent_table, curent_litera, 'f' + entered_n + '%')).fetchall()
    for i in range(len(files_4_table)):
        self.ui.table.setItem(i, 0, QTableWidgetItem(curent_rucode + files_4_table[i][0][1:].encode('utf-8')))
        item = QTableWidgetItem()
        if all_files_cur_lit[i][1] == None:
            i_count = 'Нет Записей'
        else:
            i_count = all_files_cur_lit[i][0]
        item.setData(Qt.EditRole, i_count)
        self.ui.table.setItem(i, 1, item)
        self.decimal_numbers_only.append(files_4_table[i][0][1:])

    self.decimal_numbers_only.sort()
    # Set completer for current phase and code
    completer = QCompleter()
    self.ui.lineEdit_decimal.setCompleter(completer)
    model = QStringListModel()
    completer.setModel(model)
    self.get_completer(model)
    return self.decimal_numbers_only
```

'f' конкатинируется с `entered_n`, так как в `БД`, значение `decimal` хранится в виде строки `'f123456'`. В итоге, вся эта моя байда работает, таблица динамически фильтрует значения, но в любую секунду, при вводе второй или последующих цифр (но никогда при вводе первой), приложение может тупо закрыться, без ошибки в консоль, без ничего, просто закрывается и все тут.

Если кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой, или поймет из того хлама, который я выдаю за Код, то очень прошу, разьясните, что не так? Или, может, кто-то реализовывал подобную фичу в своих приложениях, в таком случае, поделитесь опытом, пожалуйста, как можно сотворить человеческую автофильтрацию таблицы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если происходит падение, значит где-то в вызываемой функции вылетело исключение, которое не было поймано.

С помощью `sys.excepthook` можно поймать такое исключение и обработать:

```
import sys
import traceback


def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    sys.exit()


sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions


# Дальше ваш код ...
```