# Не получается собрать python-проект в exe-файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

Уже обыскал весь интернет, уже все перепробовал, но почему-то все заканчивается одним и тем же, когда запускаешь exe-файл, мгновенно запускается командная строка Windows и тут же закрывается, на этом все. Использую Python 3.6. Пробовал собирать проект через cx_Freeze и pyinstaller.

Вот код моего проекта:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class Main(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        loadUi('uis/main.ui', self)

        self.setWindowTitle('Создание простейшей визуальной программы на Python')

        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('images/logo.png'))
        self.label_img.setPixmap(QPixmap('images/main.png'))
        self.label_img.setScaledContents(True)

        self.btn_solve.clicked.connect(self.solve)
        self.btn_clear.clicked.connect(self.clear)
        self.btn_exit.clicked.connect(self.exit)

    def solve(self):
        a = self.lineEdit_a.text()
        b = self.lineEdit_b.text()
        x = self.lineEdit_x.text()

        passed = validation_of_data(a, b, x)

        if passed is True:
            a = float(a)
            b = float(b)
            x = float(x)

            answer = 0.0

            if x > 6:
                answer = a / x + b / x ** 2
            else:
                answer = a ** 2 * (x + b)

            self.label_answer.setText('Ответ: ' + str(answer))
        else:
            self.label_answer.setText('Проверьте правильность введенных данных!')

    def clear(self):
        self.lineEdit_a.setText('')
        self.lineEdit_b.setText('')
        self.lineEdit_x.setText('')
        self.label_answer.setText("Ответ: ")

    def exit(self):
        self.close()


def validation_of_data(a, b, x):
    try:
        float(a)
        float(b)
        float(x)

        return True
    except Exception:
        return False


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Уровни проекта:

```
Python-2:
---->images
---------->logo.png
---------->main.png
---->uis
---------->main.ui
---->Main.py
```

Помогите решить мою проблему! Ведь дело в том, что я смог собрать один проект с помощью pyinstaller, без проблем. В этом проекте я число рисовал с помощью turtle и никаких импортов, кроме import turtle не делал! А вот в проектах, наподобие выше, у меня почему-то не получается собрать их в exe-файл.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить хендлер и повторить: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/839397/201445 Скорее всего в сборке нужно указывать путь к библиотеками pyqt

Comment: А можно чуть поподробнее насчет хендлера и того, каким образом можно указать путь к моим библиотекам? А то, я просто новичок в этом деле!

Comment: Пример хендлера: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/master/Base64_examples/gui_base64.py#L23 . Указание пути к pyqt5: https://habr.com/post/325626/ Ищите строку "--paths" . Кст, возможно поможет установка `pip install pyqt5-tools`

Comment: Я прописал такое выражение в командной строке: "pyinstaller --onefile --paths C:\Users\(----)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin --noconsole Main.py" Но почему-то проблема не решилась, приложение не запускается и в командной строке, он как выдавал кучу таких ошибок, так и выдает их. Вот например некоторые из них: 6740 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\(----)\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe
6740 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\(----)\appdata\....

Comment: Значит, не все библиотеки были добавлены в зависимость. Добавьте также и `api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll`

Comment: Посмотрите ответ на пост https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49195741/running-the-converted-py-to-exe-file-shows-a-console-and-not-the-designed-gui/49197859#49197859  . В общем преобразуйте файл.ui в файл.py  . Только не запутайтесь с именами модулей. main.ui - это не очень  хорошо, назовите его хотя бы main_ui.ui

Comment: У вас какая OS ?

Comment: Покажите строчку командной строки с какими флагами запускаете pyinstaller

Comment: Покажите файл *spec